# Leaflet openPopup method with a click from outside the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using a Leaflet and Leafleat plugin called Leafpile on my map. Basically it's the set of the results from the database and the javascript code for this map is as follows:

```
var cmAttr = '&copy; 2013 OpenStreetMap',
cmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var minimal   = L.tileLayer(cmUrl, {styleId: 1, attribution: cmAttr})

var southWest = new L.LatLng(3.8642546157214084, -199.86328125);
var northEast = new L.LatLng(73.12494524712693 , -24.08203125);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var markers = new L.LeafpileGroup();
L.marker([40.91, -74.15]).bindPopup('The html content').addTo(markers),
L.marker([37.7, -121.90]).bindPopup('The html content').addTo(markers);

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [34.488616,-97.8692325],
    minZoom: 4,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    zoom: 5,
    layers: [minimal, markers]
});


map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

The problem that I have is that I want to open a popup (map.openPopup(popup) method or similar?!) on a map when I click on the link of the result in my html.

```
<ul id="set">
<li><a href="#">RESULT #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">RESULT #2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried everything but with no success. I want to bind this event in my jQuery function, something like:

```
$(document.body).on("click",'#set a', function(e) {
    //other code that I need
});
```

Comment: Solved :) with using variable1 =  L.marker([40.91, -74.15]).bindPopup('The html content').addTo(markers) ... and after that called with identifier using method window["variablename"].openPopup();

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to stackoverflow but I found a solution that works and seems efficient enough.

You should create an empty array first

```
var array =[]
```

The location array should contain all of your coordinates. I filled the locationarray with objects that had a location a property with a corresponding latlng value.

```
locationarray= [{name:"Hotel London",location:[51.5, -0.09]},{name:"Hotel Barnaby",location:[51.49, -0.088]},{name:"Hotel Rendelliare",location:[51.51, -0.12]},{name:"Hotel Francion",location:[51.52, -0.089]},{name:"Hotel Waterloo",location:[51.5, -0.11]}]
```

then fill the vararray with the marker objects.

```
for(i=0;i<locationarray.length;i++){

vararray[i] = L.marker(locationarray[i].location).addTo(map);
vararray[i].bindPopup('<div id="hotel'+i+'">' + locationarray[i].name + '</div>')

}
```

Then create your divs using a for loop. In the for loop assign the divs with an onclick handler or whatever you want that triggers a function. Pass into the function the value you are using to iterate over.

```
for(i=0,len = objarray.length; i<len ;i++){
$('#viewportRS').append('<div onclick="$.clicked('+i+')" class="hotels" id="'+i+'">'+ whatevervar +'</div>')}
```

The function should except the numeric parameter and call openPopup() at that index in the vararray

```
$.clicked = function(id){


vararray[id].openPopup()


}
```

I've tested it numerous times and it works. So if there is something wrong let us know.

Comment: Try to resolve a Stack Overflow question on Stack Overflow. Your e-mail is not public so other users with the same problem can't the solution, obviously.

Comment: problem can't the solution, obviously.? Didn't make sense but i gather that putting an email in a response is useless.